# C# - natively create a form window as a child to an existing window

Tags: c#, winforms, wpf-controls, pinvoke, winforms-interop

I have a C# (4.72) library that creates a window using native API’s (pinvoke). I inserted this window into an existing application successfully. So, I have a child window inserted into the existing application, and all works fine. Now I want to create a C# form as a child for that window.

I desire to create a form and set that form as a child to the previous window I inserted into that application. I have a control (WPF) that I want to insert into the form and set properties. But before starting down the xaml control path, I want to create the form and set the parent as the inserted window.

My old application was C++, and I inserted an MFC child dialog with an old control. But I have a new spec to create a modern WPF user control.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

I would really appreciate any help or suggestions that anybody might have.

Comment: You can't expect to have cross process parenting work well. Or is this all in the same process?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the same process - It is a MS Word add-in with a custom window

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I wrapped the WPF control in a library and integrated that into winform. I am using the winform as a child to my custom window.  I used pinvoke to set the parent. I defined an interface to capture all the events and integrated into my main application. It was a lot of work, but I got everything playing together nicely.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).